# Let $k$ be a field. Is $k[x,x^{-1}]$ free over $k[x]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, commutative-algebra, modules, free-modules

I see that $\{x, x^{-1}\}$ do not form a basis over $k[x]$ since for example $x^2 \cdot x^{-1} +(-1)\cdot x =0$.

I'm not sure if this is enough to conclude that $k[x,x^{-1}]$ is not free over $k[x]$.

Not sure how to proceed further.

Comment: $k[x, x^{-1}]$ is the localization of $k[x]$ at the multiplicative set generated by $x$.  In general, if $S$ is a multiplicative set of a ring $R$ consisting of non-zero divisors, then $S^{-1}R$ is a free $R$-module iff $S$ 4xconsists of units.  The proof below given by Angina Seng generalizes immediately.  $x$ is not a unit in $k[x]$, so $k[x, x^{-1}]$ cannot be free of $k[x]$.  Another way to reason, if you know a bit more commutative ring theory, is that localizations are epimorphisms and faithfully flat epimorphisms are surjective, but clearly $k[x] \not= k[x, x^{-1}]$.

Comment: @BadamBaplan What do you mean localizations are epimorphisms? The working definition of epimorphism I know of is that it is equivalent to being surjective.

Comment: An epimorphism is a right-cancellative morphism, This is a general notion in any category.  In concrete categories (where it makes sense to define surjections), surjections are always epimorphisms.  The converse is true in a number categories, e.g. sets, (finite) groups, $R$-modules, and many more.  But in the category of (commutative) rings epimorphisms are not usually surjective, as evidenced by the answer to your question.  In fact, if $R$ is a ring without nilpotents, then epimorphisms from $R$ are surjective if and only if $R$ is Von Neumann Regular.

Comment: Most of that is probably also written on the wikipedia page for epimorphisms.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epimorphism

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. If we have two nonzero elements of $k[x,x^{-1}]$ we can write then
as $x^{-r}f(x)$ and $x^{-s}g(x)$ where $f$ and $g$ lie in $k[x]$ and $r$, $s\ge0$. These
are linearly independent over $k[x]$:
$$x^rg(x)[x^{-r}f(x)]-x^sf(x)[x^{-s}g(x)]=0.$$
So if $k[x,x^{-1}]$ is free over $k[x]$ it must be free of rank $1$.

But a typical nonzero element of $k[x,x^{-1}]$ is $x^{-r}f(x)$ where $f(x)\in k[x]$
and then
$$x^{-r-1}\notin x^{-r}f(x)k[x].$$

Comment: So $k[x,x^{-1}]$ is not free over $k[x]$, correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: @AnginaSeng Do you mean to write $x^{-r}f(x)$ and $x^{-s}g(x)$ are linearly dependent over $k[x]$?

Answer (score 1):

There are similarities between $k[x]$ and $\Bbb Z$, so the question is similar to asking whether the $\Bbb Z$-module $\Bbb Z[\frac12] = \{\frac a {2^k} \in \Bbb Q: a, k\in \Bbb Z\}$ is free over $\Bbb Z$.

One possible proof is as follows:

---

Suppose $\Bbb Z[\frac12]$ is a free $\Bbb Z$-module. Let $(x_i)_i$ be a basis, and let $x_0$ be one of the $x_i$. We then consider the element $x_0/2$, which can be written as $$x_0/2 = \sum a_i x_i$$ for some integers $a_i$. Multiplying by $2$ gives $$x_0 = \sum (2a_i) x_i.$$ But on both sides we have linear combinations of basis elements, so for every basis element, the coefficients on both sides must be equal.

In particular, this means $2a_0 = 1$, which is impossible as $a_0$ is an integer.

---

The same proof works for your question: just replace $\Bbb Z$ and $2$ with $k[x]$ and $x$, respectively.